# Quasar text area for chat input

Tags: quasar-framework, quasar

The following is the text area found in
https://quasar.dev/vue-components/input#textarea

I highlighted the modification I wish to  have into different color of rectangle - I wish to make it a chat input text area.

1. red rectangle - can I disable the underlying blue line?
2. green rectangle - can I disable the resizable option?
3. yellow rectangle -  can I make the scroll bar smaller?

[image]

The ideal is the following

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Good news!

You can actually achieve everything you have mentioned! If this was a life changing dream of yours, you shall call me 'GOD'!, otherwise never-mind.

1. Disabling the underlying blue line;

use the `borderless` property

`<q-input borderless v-model="text" label="no resize arrow" type="textarea" />`

2. Disabling the resize option

use the `autogrow` property to hide the resize arrow. However, why use a `textarea` when you can have just a normal `text input box`? If you want to replace the `textarea` with a normal `textbox`, remove the `type` property

`<q-input borderless autogrow v-model="text" label="no underlying border" type="textarea" />`

If you want to resort to manual css to hide the resize icon, you can use the below css.

```
textarea {
  resize: none; /* this will disable resize for all textarea elements.  */
}
```

3. Making the scrollbar smaller

Make use of Quasar's `scrollarea` which has a very sexy looking scrollbar.

```
<q-scroll-area style="height: 200px; max-width: 300px;"> <!-- have you chat window here --> </q-scroll-area>
```

If you want to have your own custom scrollbar design; then you can follow the below snippet; but the browser support so far is limited to 'chrome'.

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
}
```